# How to Promise.all() in SuiteScript 2.0 (Netsuite)

Tags: promise, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, promise.all

So the scenario is like this: I have a Suitelet that displays lines, lines are marked with a checkbox by a user and then a "submit" button is clicked. That button calls a Client Script function that goes over the selected lines in a loop and sends https calls to the Suitelet one line at a time to submit the lines (create a custom record and update a Work Order line).

Once all lines are submited a UI message is displayed with success and error messages.

Now I want to make the HTTPS calls asynchronous which I know I can do with https.prmise BUT I can't figure out how to Prmomise.all in SuiteScript 2.0.

Help?

Comment: Are you running into a specific error or problem? I believe SuiteScript 2.0 is ECMAScript 5.1, which does not support the `Promise` API. You will need to use SuiteScript 2.1, which is ES2019 and will support `Promise.all()`.

Comment: You know I actually got it to work. I just used a https.request .promise and wrapped that in a new Promise. and then used promise all like I normally would. I was also so convinced that it wouldn't work that my first attempt just had a stupid bug in it.